# SAGE vs. Mathematica for Lie algebras / groups?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematica, sagemath

What math software is better for working with Lie algebras and Lie groups, [SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org) or Mathematica?

Comment: [Reduce](http://www.reduce-algebra.com/) has a special user contributed package on Lie algebras and Lie groups. But of course, sage is also very good.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Thanks. I also found [these SAGE tutorials](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/thematic_tutorials/toctree.html), which are very helpful. As far as I can tell, this is much better than what Mathematica can do; Mathematica doesn't seem to have anything for representing Lie groups, etc., as far as I know.

Comment: there is also LiE; http://wwwmathlabo.univ-poitiers.fr/~maavl/LiE/

Comment: See also [Lie Algebras chapter](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap64.html) from the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) manual. GAP also has a number of [packages](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/packages.html) for Lie algebras - if you're using GAP via Sage, you may need to install them manually!

Comment: Does anyone here know about Sage tickets [#14901](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/14901) or [#15635](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/15635)?